# Where can I find an NVIDIA GeForce 9800GT driver for Windows Vista/7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I obtained a new NVIDIA GeForce 9800GT today and inserted it into my computer.  I found its driver CD had no driver for Windows Vista and 7.

I downloaded the 9800GT driver for Windows 7 64-bit, but the setup gave the following error:

> The NVIDIA Setup program could not locate any drivers that are compatible with your current hardware.

Where can I find an older driver for this video card? Could there be a problem with the graphics card itself?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/win7-winvista-32bit-258.96-whql-driver-uk.html) is the 32 bit driver.